# Angular hide or show a button if the content of the field in table contains a specific text

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

In my html

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <table border="1">
           <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
           <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
           <td>{{x.City}}</td>
           <td>{{x.Country}}</td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
     <a  href="#" >Show or Hide Button</a>
```

In my controller

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.names =[
   {
    "Name" : "Max Joe",
    "City" : "Lulea",
    "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
   {
   "Name" : "Manish",
   "City" : "Delhi",
   "Country" : "India"
   }
  ];     
});
```

I need to show the button if there are no records or 1 of the country is India.    I'm working on this but no avail http://jsfiddle.net/junedc/n8ejgtwa/1/    Thanks for the help guys really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array filter as well as array length to set a boolean

```
var hasIndia = $scope.names.filter(function(item){
    return item.Country === 'India'
}).length;

$scope.showButton = !$scope.names.length || hasIndia;
```

In view:

```
<a ng-show="showButton" href="#" >Show or Hide Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl,  but I tried on my http://jsfiddle.net/n8ejgtwa/5/  and still not working :)

Comment: you put the link outside of `ng-app` and `ng-controller`. Angular won't even look at it there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n8ejgtwa/11/   i did change from India to Singapore and vice versa but still the button is not displaying.

Comment: because you are setting `showButton` before `hasIndia` is defined. Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/n8ejgtwa/12/

Comment: Thanks a lot @charlietfl.  Really really appreciated.